# Using partials in Rails 6 to divide files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `photo_upload.html.erb` file where I list all of my files.

```
<div id="photos"><%= render partial: "rooms/photos", locals: { photos: @room.images } %></div>
```

Notice that I passed in `photos` in the locals.

I then created a new file `_photos.html.erb` and place the ff code:

```
<% if @photos.count > 0 %>
<br/><br/>

<div class="row">
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <%= render partial: 'rooms/photo', locals: { photo: photo } %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And then added another partial for each individual photo by create a new file `_photo.html.erb` where I place the ff codes:

```
 <%= image_tag(photo,  class: "test_image") %>
  <%= link_to "Remove", delete_image_attachment_rooms_path(photo), class: 'delete', remote: true, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this?" } %>
```

Note that all files sits in the same folder `rooms`. However, this can't read the `photo` or `photos` even though I already passed them in to the locals.

Here's my controller for your reference:

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_room, except: [:index, :new, :create, :delete_image_attachment]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]

  def index
    @rooms = currrent_user.rooms
  end

  def new
    @room = current_user.rooms.create
  end

  def create
    @room = current_user.rooms.create(room_params)

    if @room.save
      redirect_to listing_room_path(@room), notice: "Saved..."
    else 
      flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong!"
      render :new
    end 
  end

  def show
  end 

  def listing
  end

  def pricing
  end

  def description
  end

  def photo_upload
  end

  def amenities
  end

  def location
  end

  def update
    if @room.update(room_params)
      @room.images.attach(params[:room][:room_images])
      
      flash[:notice] = "Saved..."
    else 
      flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong..."
    end 
    redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referrer)
  end

  def delete_image_attachment
    @image = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find_by(params[:id])
    @image&.purge
    # flash[:notice] = "Image deleted..."
    # redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referrer)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js 
    end
  end

  private


  def set_room
    @room = Room.find(params[:id])
  end 

  def room_params
    params.require(:room).permit(:home_type, :room_type, :accomodate, :bed_room, :bath_room, :listing_name, :summary, :address, :is_tv, :is_kitchen, :is_air, :is_heating, :is_internet, :price, :active, images: [])
  end 
end
```

I am wondering what am I doing wrong here in order to divide the partials and still can make it work. Am I doing something wrong with the locals and partial naming?

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a local variable into a partial, it does not have an `@` prefix. `@photos` is not how you use a local delivered by `locals: { photos: ... }`, you need `photos`.

Exactly how you use `photo` in your `_photos` partial, and not `@photo`.

Note also that you're using a dated syntax. You can replace these...

```
render partial: "rooms/photos", locals: { photos: @room.images }
render partial: 'rooms/photo', locals: { photo: photo }
```

with these:

```
render 'rooms/photos', photos: @room.images
render 'rooms/photo', photo: photo
```

The results are identical.